# Zabbix 2.2 API get Processor load (1 min average) min/max value from_time, till_time

Tags: python, zabbix

I want to get the CPU usage average/max for a month of a host (for 1 min average per core). I can get this in the `Zabbix` web gui `CPU load` graph.

I checked the [pyzabbix](https://github.com/lukecyca/pyzabbix/blob/master/examples/trend_data.py) example and the `zabbix` api document but I still don't know how to get the avg/max CPU usage from_time - till_time.

For example when I call:

```
history = zapi.history.get(itemids=[item_id],
        time_from=time_from,
        time_till=time_till,
        output='extend',
        limit='5000',
        history=0,
    )
```

I get many values of CPU usage for each 1 min from the range of time I use -> I have to use that data to calculate the min/avg/max ?

How Zabbix generate those kind of info in graph? Does it make a calculation like that every time we generate graph view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whenever a graph is generated in Zabbix, it fetches all historical data for the specified period and calculates minimum, average, and maximum values, in addition to plotting the graph.

With Zabbix frontend itself, plotting graphs for longer periods of time is less heavyweight, because in such cases it takes the data from trend tables. For instance:

```
mysql> describe trends;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| itemid    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| clock     | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| num       | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| value_min | double(16,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
| value_avg | double(16,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
| value_max | double(16,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Each row in this table corresponds to one hour and the minimum, average, and maximum values are stored for this hour. So when plotting a graph for a longer period of time, the frontend takes data from trends and has thus much less data to process.

Unfortunately, trend data does not seem to be available through Zabbix API, but such a feature is requested in [ZBXNEXT-1193](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1193).

Comment: Thanks guys. I am using history call to get all statistic of the items then do some calculation to get what I want. Not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix server polls its agent according to frequency set in the template and brings and stores the value in database.When we click on graph it creates a graph from those values fetching them from database.You can specify the type of input whether you want percentage or decimal or integer in the template attached to the host.You can specify the time period for the graph and it will calculate the values for that specific period.The values are based on the values in database.